# Javascript function shows only last element of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, html

Please take a look at this function:

```
var msgdiv, i=0;
msgdiv=$("#message");
messages=["Welcome!","Добро пожаловать!"];
function fadeMessages(messages, div){
    while(i<messages.length){
        div.fadeOut(1000).html('').append(messages[i]).fadeIn(1000);
        i=i+1;
    }  
}
 fadeMessages(messages,msgdiv);
```

What I want to do is, to show one by one elements of array. But, function above shows only last element of array `messages.length` time. Where I did wrong?

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/QQy6X/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `while` executes much *much* faster than the `fadeOut`/`fadeIn` calls, so you only see the last result. You need to make each animation wait for the previous ones to finish.

I like to solve these problems recursively. Note, it does alter the `messages` array, but it's not too hard to convert this to use a counter instead (like your original version). Here you go:

```
var $msgdiv = $('#message'),
    messages = ['Xoş gəlmişsiniz!', 'Welcome!', 'Добро пожаловать!'];

function showNext() {
    var msg = messages.shift();
    if (msg) {
        $msgdiv.fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(this).text(msg).fadeIn(1000, showNext);
        });
    }
}

showNext();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Exj95/

---

Here's a version that leaves `messages` intact:

```
var $msgdiv = $('#message'),
    messages = ['Xoş gəlmişsiniz!', 'Welcome!', 'Добро пожаловать!'],
    i = 0;

function showNext() {
    if (i < messages.length) {
        var msg = messages[i];
        $msgdiv.fadeOut(1000, function () {
            i++;
            $(this).text(msg).fadeIn(1000, showNext);
        });
    }
}

showNext();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/wALfP/

Comment: I can't figure out how to " make each animation wait for the previous ones "

Comment: You need to refresh the page, my friend `;-)`

Comment: and how to get it work with delay between fadein() and fadeout()?

Comment: Learn to search [the jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/), man. I'll give you a hint: [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6099/discussion-between-m-ll-and-tural-teyyuboglu)

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop finishes executing before the div has had a chance to fade out.  Use an `if` statement and recursion:

```
var msgdiv = $("#message"); 
var i = 0; 
var messages = ["Welcome!", "Добро пожаловать!"]; 
(function fadeMessages() { 
    if (i in messages) { 
        msgdiv.fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(this).html('').append(messages[i++]).fadeIn(1000, fadeMessages);
        });
    } 
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QQy6X/6/

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you can't intertwine animations and non-animations in the way you are doing and expect them to run in the right order.  The animations will go into the animation queue and get sequenced one after another there, but the non-animations will all run immediately.  Thus, things won't happen in the right order.

To do something like you want to do, you can use code like this.

```
messages=["Welcome!","Добро пожаловать!"];

function fadeMessages(msgs, div) {
    var i = 0;
    function next() {
        if (i < msgs.length) {
            div.fadeOut(1000, function() {
                div.html(msgs[i++]).fadeIn(1000, next);
            });
        }
    }
    next();
}

fadeMesssages(messages, div);
```

This uses the completion functions of both `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` to carry out the next steps.  Here's how it works:

1. It fades out the div.
2. In the completion function of the fadeOut, it sets the next message and then starts the fadeIn.
3. It advances the message counter.
4. In the completion function from the fadeIn, it calls the function to start the next iteration.

If you want a delay before the fadeOut (to make sure a given message displays for a certain amount of time), you can add that with this `.delay(2000)` added in the right place:

```
messages=["Welcome!","Добро пожаловать!"];

function fadeMessages(msgs, div) {
    var i = 0;
    function next() {
        if (i < msgs.length) {
            div.delay(2000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                div.html(msgs[i++]).fadeIn(1000, next);
            });
        }
    }
    next();
}

fadeMesssages(messages, div);
```

If you want a delay before the next iteration starts, you can do that like this with a setTimeout:

```
messages=["Welcome!","Добро пожаловать!"];

function fadeMessages(msgs, div) {
    var i = 0;
    function next() {
        if (i < msgs.length) {
            div.fadeOut(1000, function() {
                div.html(msgs[i++]).fadeIn(1000, function() {
                    setTimeout(next, 2000);
                });
            });
        }
    }
    next();
}

fadeMesssages(messages, div);
```

Comment: and how to set delay before next()?

Comment: Your original code had no delay between each iteration other than the fadeIn, fadeOut times, but I've added two new versions to my answer that have a 2 second delay.  The first is before the fadeOut at the start of each iteration.  The second is before the next iteration starts.  The former is easier because you can just use `.delay()`.  The second uses `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop finishes very quickly; instead you should wait for the animation to finish before starting the next one. This is easy to do by adding a callback function to fadeIn. I would use this:

```
+function(){
    var $msgdiv = $("#message");
    var i = -1;
    var messages = ["Xoş gəlmişsiniz!","Welcome!","Добро пожаловать!"];

    +function fadeNext(){
        $msgdiv.fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $msgdiv.text(messages[i = (i + 1) % messages.length]);
            $msgdiv.fadeIn(1000, fadeNext);
        });        
    }();
}();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/QQy6X/7/

Comment: and how to get it work with delay between fadein() and fadeout()?

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu Add `.delay(1000);` after the fadeIn, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/QQy6X/8/